# SQL Alter table Statement for columns containing data array

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

The column of my table that has following kind of data :column name 'html_data':

```
 <h2 class="blue">Safely does it</h2>
<p>Contemplating a dive off your hotel balcony into the pool? Planning to hop onto a 
<a href="http://">moped in Bali</a> y risks. Before leaping off into the abyss, check, do you have travel insurance? And if so, would you be covered for <a href="http">?</a></p>
<h2 class="green">Respect the relics</h2>
```

i need a sql statement that finds the `href="http` and change it to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `replace()`, I think:

```
select replace(html_data, 'href="http:', 'href='https:')
```

You can put this in an update:

```
update t
    set html_data = replace(html_data, 'href="http:', 'href='https:');
```

Comment: i alo want to search for url  in column with data like <link rel="canonical" href="https://" /><style type="text/css"> .speech-bubble{font-size:21px !important;}</style>
 i tried :select custom_tags from page where custom_tags like'%http://'
is there a way to find only the href iitem .

Comment: select id,html_content from t where html_content ~ 'href="http://www.',i was able to select also using the above answer